# Populating email no longer working after adding PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" to input claim

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an orchestration step that collects the users email address before the combinedSignInSignup orchestration step.  The email address was populating both the signin and signup screens successfully.  I needed to add email verification to the signup screen, which I accomplished by adding PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" to the input claim for LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail technical profile.  Now the email address is no longer populated.

```
           <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
                <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
                    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
                    <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <CryptographicKeys>
                    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
                </CryptographicKeys>
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email"/>
                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />

                    <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="telephoneNumber" Required="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="facsimileTelephoneNumber" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobile" Required="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="customer_account_number"/>
                </OutputClaims>
                <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
                </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of PartnerClaimType in your input claim. It’s only needed on outputclaim here.

Comment: That's how i viewed the documentation as well but that's not working.  I had to add the partnerclaimtype to the input claim to get that to work.  If i remove the partnerclaimtype from the input claim the email address is no longer validated.

Comment: Did you change the email first after it is prepopulated? Since email verification options will only appear if the prepopulated claim is changed by the user.